# How to save google search queries urls?

Tags: google-search

I have a rather simple task that takes me hours to complete on a regular basis. What I would like to do is search my website on google using the `site:www.example.com` command and save the urls that popup.

Since my site is pretty big, the results are plenty. I use this information for SEO purposes and would really appreciate a simple program that would list all the results and be able to save it in a csv format. I tried SEOQuake with firefox and I found it too heavy weight that it slowed my computer down everytime it was open.

Comment: You could try the [custom search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) from Google. With the free can run upto 100 queries/day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try scraping the results with Xpath - here is how:

http://vancouverdata.blogspot.co.il/2011/02/how-to-web-scraping-xpath-html-google.html

I use a similar method but with Niels Bosma (excellent!) Excel SEO Tools

http://nielsbosma.se/projects/seotools/